# Read JSON from from HTML file input

Tags: javascript, html, json, file-io

If I have an input:

```html
<input type="file" id="upload" onchange="getFile(this)">
```

And my user will upload a JSON file (as plaintext, so I will have to use `JSON.parse()`), how can I take this file and actually get the data via `getFile()`

In `getFile(element)`, I've tried using `element.files[0]` but that doesn't seem to contain the actual data. I've also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711002/how-can-i-get-javascript-to-read-from-a-json-file), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60909282/html-read-json-input), but none of these solve my problem. [This resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications) on MDN seems promising, but I don't really get it.

I would like a solution involving either `URL.createObjectURL()` or `FileReader()`.

Also, before anyone posts this in the comments, I do understand that these solutions do not work on all browsers, and I would like to do this from the frontend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take advantage of the [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) constructor and call `.json()` on any blob/file.

```
function getFile (elm) {
  new Response(elm.files[0]).json().then(json => {
    console.log(json)
  }, err => {
    // not json
  })
}
```

Alternative method using the new read methods on blob.prototype[...]

```
new Blob(['1']).text().then(JSON.parse).then(console.log)
// handles emptying file input with ?.
elm.files[0]?.text().then(JSON.parse).then(console.log)
```

I guess for larger files response.json might be faster/better since it can parse the content in background and not block the main UI unlike JSON.parse

Comment: Thanks, it works! I like this answer's brevity and the fact that it also handles errors more easily. Although it didn't use either of those methods I mentioned, I'd argue it's a better solution.

Comment: This is great! Far more concise than using FileReader.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this api:

[FileReader Api From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

[JSON#parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

[View In Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-aksq8q?embed=1&file=index.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Read Text</title>
  <style>
    div {
     margin-top: 30px;
     border: solid 1px black;
     padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function processFiles(files) {
      var file = files[0];

      var message = document.getElementById("message");
      message.innerHTML = "File Name：" + file.name + "<br>";
      message.innerHTML += "File Size：" + file.size + "<br>";
      message.innerHTML += "File Type：" + file.type + "<br>";

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        var output = document.getElementById("fileOutput");  
        // parse string to json 
        output.textContent = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="fileInput" type="file" size="50" onchange="processFiles(this.files)">
  <div id="message"></div>
  <div id="fileOutput"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might consider adding a `try/catch` in case `JSON.parse()` throws error from bad file